# How to position a button inside an li?

Tags: html, css

How can I position this button in the left-bottom corner of the "li"? The button is now in the left-center when defining `bottom: 0;` and `left: 3%;`.

Code which appends the li to the html page:

```
const setupPosts = (data) => {
            let html = '';
            data.forEach(doc => {
                const post = doc.data();
                const picURL = post.picURL;
                var path = doc.ref.path;
                let li = `<li class="post">
                    <div class="content">${post.content}</div>
                    <button class="comment" onclick="comment('${path}')">Comment</button>
                    <button class="like" onclick="like('${path}')">Like</button>`;
                
                li += (post.picURL ? `<img class="img" src="${post.picURL}" onclick="openImage('${picURL}')">` : ``);
                li += `</li><br></br>`;
                html += li
            })
            
            posts.innerHTML = html;
        }
```

CSS:

```
.comment {
    background-color: #006FC4;
    border: 1px solid #00508D;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 3%;
}

.like {
    background-color: #006FC4;
    border: 1px solid #00508D;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: make a reproducible example, pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/velid/g42faLn3/26/

```
.comment {
    /* rest of the code */
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #00508D;
    height: 30px;

    /* new part */
    bottom: calc(-100% + 30px + 1px); /* 30px is height of the element and 1px is border width */
}
```